# swift replacingOccurrences regular expression with number calculation

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

I have `[size=some_number%]some_text[/size]`, and I want to replace it with

```
<font size="some_number*font_size">sometext</font>
```

where font_size is some int variable
I know how to extract some_number and some_text with regular expression, but how can I do the multiplie calculation ? Is there a way to do it in swift justing using replacingOccurrences?

```
#"\[size=(d+)%\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/size\]"#
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do it in swift justing using replacingOccurrences?

ICU regular expressions don't do math. You'll have to deal with these one at a time, doing the search, performing the calculation, and then doing the replace for that occurrence, repeating that in a loop. Loop in reverse to avoid index-shifting issues.

For instance:

```
var s = """
yo[size=6%]ooo[/size]heyho[size=10%]yyy[/size]ha
"""
let font_size = 10
let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\[size=(\\d+)%\\]([\\s\\S]*?)\\[\\/size\\]", options: [])
let matches = reg.matches(in: s, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: s.utf16.count))
let rev = matches.reversed() // work backwards for replacement
for match in rev {
    let r = match.range
    let size = s[Range(match.range(at:1), in:s)!]
    let text = s[Range(match.range(at:2), in:s)!]
    let prefix = "<font size=\""
    let num = String(Int(size)!*font_size)
    let rest = "\">" + text + "</font>"
    s = s.replacingCharacters(in: Range(r, in:s)!, with: prefix + num + rest)
}
print(s)
```

Now `s` is

```
yo<font size="60">ooo</font>heyho<font size="100">yyy</font>ha
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the mutation of a collection invalidates *all* indices (not only those at and after the point of the mutation). But I do not know if that that actually can be a problem for strings.